# Understanding the "Welcome to Play 2.0" page creation

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have just started to try to work with the play framework and tried to understand this default application you get when creating a new project.

So as far as I understand, when loading the localhost page, a http get request comes in and is directed to the `Application.index()` method because of the specification in the routes file?
In the `index()` method a lot of HTML code is generated and returned in a Result object and passed to the `index.scala.html` file which hands it over to the `main.scala.html` where it is surrounded with more html.

Now, a few things are unclear to me:

- in `Application.java` there is this line `return ok(index.render("Hello World!"));`
  index belongs to `views.html.*`; but where is this package? I can't find it in the API :(
- why can't I rename the `index.scala.html` file? Is the name a convention?
- in the `index.scala.html` file itself: what does `@play20.welcome(message, style = "Java")` do? is this getting the "Welcome to Play 2.0" site? and again - I can't find the documentation/API entry for the play20 thing :(

I hope, somebody can help me to get an overview, as I am really confused at the moment..^^
I have done a lot of java, but no web programming at all, therefore this mix of all the different technologies and languages is quite strange at the moment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [TodoList example](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaTodoList), the site root `GET /` is mapped to the method `Application.index()`, so this method creates the html you are seeing.

Everything the controller does happens in this line: `return ok(index.render("Hello World!"));`. Basically it calls some templates which generate html and returns the output.

- `return ok( ... )` is used to indicate a successful request, return code 200.
- `index.render( ... )` returns the rendered html output of a template named `index`. The package used here is `views.html.*` but it actually refers to `views/index.scala.html`. So the `index` part is no convention, you can rename that part as you like. The template needs to get compiled before it is usable like a Java class, that's why the package names are different. The framework takes care of this.
- `"Hello World!"` is the argument, as specified as *message* parameter in the very first line of `index.scala.html`
- `@play20.welcome( ... )` just calls another template, a [welcome page](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/play20/welcome.scala.html) which is included in the framework. It's not a subject to change - it's just static page, after removing that line from the view you can put any HTML you want.

Comment: thank you! :)
.. especially for the link to the welcome page on GIT!